# Python Script for percent change in NPP ( Net Primary Production)

Tags: python, raster

Can you suggest a python script for percent change raster from "begin year"(Inras1) to "end year" (Inras2) Vegetation Net Primary Production rasters? Example: That is a given raster cell increased by 25% compared to "begin year"

`

Comment: Please show evidence of some research and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Name: Minus_Ex_02.py
 # Description: Modification of ESRI's Subtracts the value of the second                      input raster from the Value of the first input raster on a cell-by-cell basis
  # Requirements: Spatial Analyst Extension
  # Author: ESRI

  # Import system modules
  import arcpy
  from arcpy import env
  from arcpy.sa import *

  # Set environment settings
  env.workspace = "C:/Users/Kaleab/Desktop/MOD17A3/Mosaic/Clip"

  # Set local variables
  inRaster1 = "2000clip.tif"
  inRaster2 = "2010clip.tif"

  # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
  arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

 # Execute Minus
 outMinus = Minus(inRaster1, inRaster2)
 changeras = outMinus/inRaster1
 # Save the output 
 changeras.save("C:/Users/Kaleab/Desktop/MOD17A3/Mosaic/Clip/Change.tif")
```